# Listen for value change on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to do a simple alert when the value is changed, but the value of the select element is changed with an slider so onchange isn't working. How can I listen for the value change and alert new value using javascript or jquery?

```
<select name="speed" id="speed" onchange="alert(this.value)">
    <option value="10mi">less than 10 miles</option>
    <option value="20mi">less than 20 miles</option>
    <option value="40mi" selected="selected">less than 40 miles</option>
    <option value="60mi">less than 60 miles</option>
    <option value="Off">Off</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What slider are you talking about? Also what browser?

Comment: What you have is correct - you probably need to fix your slider

Comment: the slider works and changes the value of the dropdown correctly. It's just that the onchange doesn't fire unless the user actually uses the dropdown (which is not displayed). You can see it here: `http://chusmix.com/twtdeal/browse/`

Comment: Oh so your slider changes the select element but it doesn't fire the select element's onchange event. Is that what you meant? Why would you need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the slider change.

```
$( "some-slider-selector" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
  // use ui.value for the value
});
```

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change

When you change the textbox value with JS, it doesn't trigger the change event. It may be a similar case with the dropdown, that's why you'll have to handle it on the side that triggered it.